# How to right insert long line in <LI> nested comments?

Tags: html, css

Long line in title move author on next line

html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="test">
      <li>
        <span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span>
        <ul class="test">
          <li><span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span></li>
          <li><span class="title">Comment very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span>
            <ul class="test">
              <li><span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span>
            <ul class="test">
              <li><span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span></li>
      <li><span class="title">Comment</span><span class="date">18.09.2017 10:47</span><span class="author">author</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  font: 10pt Arial,Tahoma,sans-serif;
  width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.odd > li {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.even > li {
  background-color: white;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 0 none;
  margin: 1px;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
.author {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 110px;
  float: right;
}
.date {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  width: 110px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/67x5b8v8/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can set a width on the `.title` element and set a overflow ellipses so it will display three dots at the end of the title, like this:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

For more info on how ellipses works see this article on  [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/)

Comment: i can't set .title width. width is different on nested levels.

Comment: Set the width with percentage, so it will work across all levels

Comment: i try it in jsfiddle. don't work. and why title nowrap? i need wrap long comments.